# Weird terminal behavior with "git difftool"

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-14.04, git-difftool

When I try to use "git difftool", the terminal seems to enter a mode where hitting the "enter" key outputs ^M instead of accepting the default option:

```
$ git difftool --tool=tkdiff file

Viewing (1/1): 'file'
Launch 'tkdiff' [Y/n]: ^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M
```

I can control-c out of it, but I can't get difftool to work.

"git diff" works like a charm.

I am struggling to Google for this problem.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, my TERM is xterm, and my .gitconfig is very simple, it has nothing about output in it:

```
[user]
        name = My Name
        email = myemail@example.com

[alias]
        co = checkout
```

How can I use "git difftool"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a terminal configuration problem rather than a git issue. Run `stty sane` to see if that helps or follow other instructions in this similar post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/441744/pressing-enter-produces-m-instead-of-a-newline

Comment: stty sane worked. Thank you! I am so surprised, since the terminal otherwise seemed to be working fine.

Comment: Great! Haven't had this particular error myself but I'll keep a bookmark to you question just in case he he...